# Window animation is not running smoothly

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing an application in C# using WPF and I wanted to add resize window animation after a button click event. My problem is that the animation is not running as smooth as expected. On an empty application all is good.

```
double final = 800.0;
double initial = 223.0;

DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
animation.To = final;
if (this.Width == final) { animation.To = initial; }

this.BeginAnimation(Window.WidthProperty, animation);
```

How can i make the animation to run smoothly?